# SSJS OR Java equivilent of producing a Yes/No Prompt

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

Domino 9.0.1
Notes / Designer 9.0.1
ExtLibs 9.0.1_*
browser any -- must work for IE9+

This is a question that I have looked into a lot, and I have had no real luck.  I am new to Dojo and to AJAX, but am hoping that someone has tried this already.

**The use-case**
I am in the process of creating my own XPage utility which I will be using for just about every other application I plan on creating.

Using the simple actions in a button event (for example), it is possible to ask the user a "yes no" question to plan out which events will be fired next.  Using the xe:toolbar, this is not an option as far as I am aware.  I am looking for a way to accomplish this same task via SSJS or Java that is reusable.  Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

I have been looking into possibilities with `dojo.xhrget / -post` but feel a tad bit out of my league.  Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**
After taking another look, it is possible to use the simple actions for the toolbar, but it would still be nice to look into this functionality for other uses.  Basically, the desire would be to have any sort of prompt be called via the server side code and the answer supplied to the calling function.

Answer (score 1):

Greg,

a Yes/No prompt is a UI interaction. Java and SSJS are server side languages. By definition they can't trigger any UI interaction.

You need to plan your flow accordingly. You can use client side JS to do the prompting (e.g. using a Dojo Dialog). Your server side code could check if a value is set, if no, then unhide your control with the prompt and terminate processing. In the control the value gets set and the action tried again.

As the nature of web applications go: HTTP is your boundary you don't want to cross if you don't have to

Comment: @greg There is a simple action for SSJS called "Confirm Action". You can chain it with "Execute Script" simple action.